# Qt application title

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface, gnome

I'm developping a Qt application

I managed to set the main window title using methode

```
setWindowTitle("my title");
```

however this changes the name in the application top bar, it doesn't affect the title displayed in the top bar of gnome shell (ubuntu) nor the title displayed when doing alt+tab.

How to change it ?

I've tried using the DEPLOYMENT.display_name variable in my .pro file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("your title") in your main code.

Comment: This bug was about Gnome 3 and Qt 4.7.4, it is currently closed and now lives at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-22274

Answer (score 6):

Once properly set programmatically, to get the application name for use as title just use the static getter method [`QCoreApplication::applicationName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop) or [`QtGUIApplication::applicationDisplayName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#applicationDisplayName-prop) (since V5).

From V5, these will fall back to the executable name if the property is not set.

Example use:

```
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName( QString("My Application") );
setWindowTitle( QCoreApplication::applicationName() );
```

Alternatively, set the Window title with Qt Designer and access it with `windowTitle()`.

Answer (score 4):

The *application name* is distinct from the *window title*. The window manager usually draws the *window title* into the *title bar* of the (main) window, while the *application name* is used by (e.g. Gnome) to represent the *application* itself.

Qt seems to be passing on the *first argument's first item* of its *constructor's signature* to the underlying window-manager:

```py
app = QApplication(('My Application Name',))
```

`QApplication.applicationName` seems to be mainly used for [application-internal purposes](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QCoreApplication.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationName).

---

A more complete (basic) set-up would then look something like this (in Python, C++ would be analogous) - not the invocation of `MyQApplication`'s superclass's constructor:

```py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class MyQApplication(QtGui.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, app_name):
        super(MyQApplication, self).__init__((app_name,))

        self.setApplicationName(app_name)

        self.main_window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        self.main_window.setWindowTitle("My Application's Main Window")
        self.main_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyQApplication("My Application's Name")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Designer in Qt Creator and change the title of the object in settings,which are on the right side.